# .htaccesss similar rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I presume one overwrites the other, I'm not really familiar with the conditions in `.htaccess` Rules

This is the current one:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /article.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /cat.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If I use as is, the cat RewriteRule won't work, if I specify a path `^cat/([^/]*)$` it will, so I presume the article `RewriteRule` overwrites the latter. How can I make both rules co-exist? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "if I specify a path `^cat/([^/]*)$` it will" - So why didn't you keep that in place? What URLs are you trying to match? What should happen to a request for `/foo`?

Comment: Hey and thanks for the comment. That's exactly it, when requesting /foo it will fetch an article slug ID i'm using, I want to be able to use the same rule for cat id fetch, sorry if I use unrelated terminology

Comment: "I want to be able to use the same rule for cat id fetch" - But then how do you differentiate between URLs that should be sent to `article.php` and those that should be sent to `cat.php`? Why should `/foo` be sent to _article_ and not _cat_? What about `/bar`?

Comment: Because they won’t share the same ID/Slug ?

Comment: So, what differentiates them? How do you determine that one URL should be sent to `article.php` and another URL should be sent to `cat.php`?

Comment: I get what you’re saying, I was sure I’ve seen this accomplished somewhere else, so better stick to paths, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you re looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?cat/([^/]*)$ /cat.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The point is that your matching patterns need to differ somehow, since the engine has to have some aspect to decide what rule to apply when.

Comment: Hello friend and thanks for the reply. What I want to accomplish is using the home path directory as identifiers for both article id and cat id, and I believe it counteract each other. Is there any other method I could use to accomplish what I'm asking for?

Comment: You can obviously not use the same URL to target two different resources. How should the http server distinguish between the two? If you can answer that it is possible to implement a rule. But so far you have _not_ answered that question.

Comment: Like answered above, they obviously won’t share the same ID/URL

Comment: Sorry, but I did not spot any such differenciation above. Could you please explain that? In your previous comment you wrote "using the home path directory as identifiers". To me that sounds like you want to use the path to the "home folder", so the path "/", as URL for _both_ resources. If that is _not_ what you tried to express, then please give precise and clear examples for what you are actually talking about. What URL should get rewritten to what internal resource? My answer may be wrong. But that is because I had to _guess_ what you are looking for.